# Where and when were air guns used in a major battle?

Tags: europe, weapons, battle, modern

In the 18th century some European armies had air guns at their disposal.
I remember that during some major battle sharpshooters from Tirol used air guns to deadly effect on the troops of the opposing side. Where and when was that battle fought?

One example of air gun is the [Girandoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girandoni_air_rifle).

Comment: Very likely during the 1809 campaign, when the Tyrolese three times ejected Bavarian occupiers until, after Znaim, Napoleon was able to bring the entire weight of his superior force against them. However I recall no mention of this weapon in John H. Gill's *With Eagles to Glory*.: https://www.amazon.ca/With-Eagles-Glory-Napoleon-Campaign/dp/1848325827?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0

Answer (score 7):

There is little evidence for the use air rifles on a large scale in battle, though they were used by sharp-shooters from Tyrol in the Austrian army in battle from at least 1789 at the Siege of Belgrade; despite some advantages, they presented too many battlefield problems and fell out of use by 1815.

---

Developed in the late 1770s, in 1780 the [Girandoni air rifle](http://firearmshistory.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-girandoni-repeating-air-rifle.html)

> was adopted for use in the Austrian army, where it was called a
>   Windbuchse (literally meaning "wind rifle" in German). The rifle was
>   in use by the Austrian military until around 1815 and was used against
>   in battles against the Turks. Japan and France were also other users
>   of this type of weapon.

[image]

*Girandoni Air Rifle. Source: [Defense Media Network, originally from the the National Firearms Museum](https://www.defensemedianetwork.com/stories/the-girandoni-air-rifle/).*

The weapon was initially issued to Austria’s fusilier regiment but

> Rough handling and improper maintenance caused frequent malfunctions.
>   Thus, Emperor Joseph had his secret weapons redistributed to
>   specifically trained Tyrolean sharpshooters who better understood how
>   to care for these rather delicate weapons.

Source: J. Plaster, *[History of Sniping and Sharpshooting](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_History_Of_Sniping_And_Sharpshooting.html?id=XpceLgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) (2008)*

Apparently, only around [1,500 Girandoni air rifles were ever made](https://www.defensemedianetwork.com/stories/the-girandoni-air-rifle/). There is some disagreement among the sources as to how extensively, and in which campaigns, the Girandoni air rifle was used. Plaster claims that:

> During Austria’s 1788-89 war against Turkey and a 1790 fight with
>   Prussia, the Girandoni air rifle was used extensively and proved
>   itself in combat, offering a high rate, reasonable accuracy, and
>   lethality, without generating gun smoke or muzzle blast. One Tyrolean
>   sharpshooter report noted, “These weapons were really accurate and
>   effective.”

Although the attributes of the rifle are not contested by other sources, when and where (and how widely used it was) leads to some disagreement. No source disputes they had been issued to Austrian troops, as Plaster states, in the 1788-89 war with Turkey. However, the adversaries spent most of 1788 avoiding each other on the battlefield. After the [Battle of Karansebes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Kar%C3%A1nsebes) (1788), 20 air rifles were captured by the Ottomans, but this was a friendly-fire incident and the Ottoman's didn't arrive on the scene until two days after the 'battle'.

According to this well-referenced [article](http://www.beemans.net/Austrian%20airguns.htm), it was shortly after the Karansebes incident that the air rifles were assigned to the Tyrolians.

> ...it was deemed wise to take back the airguns and issue them only to
>   select, specially trained Tyrolean sharpshooter units. The last order
>   given by the Emperor prior to his death was “to select the most
>   promising and skilful soldiers to use these guns.”

Given that it was a select few, and given the expense and complications involved in the use of these air rifles, Paster's 'extensive use' seems to be an overstatement, especially as there was little real fighting in 1788.

[This source concurs](http://www.napoleon-series.org/cgi-bin/forum/archive2015_config.pl?md=read;id=167857):

> Airguns were never widely used even when fielded in 1788-1789. Then
>   when Joseph II died in 1790 chances of any wider use was extremely
>   limited. It became a specialist tool.

In addition to the aforementioned expenses and complications, this was in large part because they

> could not stand up to field use, with the repeater frequently breaking
>   down and leather seals failing.

*Source: Plaster*

As the sources agree that the Tyroleans used them, this must have been mostly in 1789 at the [Battle of Focșani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Foc%C8%99ani) and/or the [Battle of Rymnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Rymnik) and/or the [Siege of Belgrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Belgrade_(1789)). The latter seems most probable for the air rifle proved to be [effective at sieges](http://www.napoleon-series.org/cgi-bin/forum/archive2015_config.pl?md=read;id=167857). [This source](http://nsfarchives.altervista.org/napoleon/forum/archive2016_config.pl@md=read%3Bid=176868.html) (citing the Vienna military archives) claims that their use was planned at the Siege of Belgrade.

Despite some successes, though, the air gun was destined for use in [specialist operations](http://www.napoleon-series.org/cgi-bin/forum/archive2015_config.pl?md=read;id=167857) only

> The next known usage was another attempt of a coup de main at Legnano
>   in 1796 that was a virtual replay of Belgrade 1787. It too failed. The
>   AMA [Austrian Military Airgun] was seen by some in the Austrian
>   military (most importantly Francis I) as a valuable tool for secret
>   night operations.

Whether they were used against Napoleon's forces or not is disputed. [Frederick J. Chiaventone](http://warfarehistorynetwork.com/daily/military-history/lewis-and-clarks-girandoni-air-rifle/) and [Robert D. Beeman](http://www.beemans.net/Austrian%20airguns.htm) state that, despite what many sources claim, it was not, and that Naploeon's statement about having [users of the rifles hanged](http://www.beemans.net/Austrian%20airguns.htm) is fabricated.

> The late Arne Hoff, famed arms historian and curator of the Royal
>   Danish Arsenal, and others, have commented that this story, told as
>   the “eye witness” war experience of French General Mortier, has now
>   been quite thoroughly refuted (Baer, 1973).  This story may have grown
>   from the fact that many towns, fearing these unfamiliar, terrifying
>   guns - even without any negative incidents, banned airguns.